# How to reduce non-digits or unknowns in a matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

I have reduced this matrix to this point, but I am struggling on how to reduced it even more. If possible.

```
   1  0  -2    3
   0  1  1/a  -2/a
   0  0  a-1  a+2
```

Comment: Multiply the third row with $1/(a-1)$.

Comment: Thanks alots that what I couldn't figure out. I kept dividing it by a but that didn't get rid of it. I am guessing its not possible to get rid of the a in the second row?? If I muliply by a then (2, 2) becomes 1a.

Answer (score 1):

These are the next steps:$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & \frac1a & -\frac2a \\
0 & 0 & a-1 & a+2 \\
\end{array}\right]\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & \frac1a & -\frac2a \\
0 & 0 & \frac1a & {a+2 \over a(a-1)} \\
\end{array}\right] \to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -{a+2 \over a(a-1)}-\frac2a \\
0 & 0 & \frac1a & {a+2 \over a(a-1)} \\
\end{array}\right]\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 3+2{a+2 \over a-1} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -{a+2 \over a(a-1)}-\frac2a \\
0 & 0 & 1 & {a+2 \over a-1} \\
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & {5a+1 \over a-1} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -{3 \over a-1} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & {a+2 \over a-1} \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

If $a=0$, the matrix is undefined from the very begginning.

If $a=1$, the matrix is:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{array}\right]\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: Thanks.I need to practise this.

Comment: yes, no worries... the algebra was scary

Comment: This is not allowed for $a = 0, a = 1$. These cases should be treated separately.

Comment: These cases undefine the figures, as usually.

Comment: The question changed, i will review it soon

Answer (score 0):

If $a\ne 1$:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-2&3\\0&1&\frac1a&-\frac2a\\0&0&a-1&a+2
\end{bmatrix}&\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-2&3\\0&1&\frac1a&-\frac2a\\0&0&1&\frac{a+2}{a-1}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\frac{5a+1}{a-1}\\0&1&0&-\frac3{a-1}\\0&0&1&\frac{a+2}{a-1}
\end{bmatrix}&
\end{align}

If $a=1$, it is already reduced:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-2&3\\0&1&1&-2\\0&0&0&3
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks. This helps alot. So if a = 1, there is no solution. Can there be infinite many possible solutions if a is not equal 1?

Comment: If this is the augmented matrix of a linear system, yes there's no solution.